# create an object array from a form in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

This is the kind of ptoblem that in python i take two minutes to solve but in js or jquery i fight for hours...
i have a form and i need to elaborate the data client-side.

With :

```
var serializedData = $('form#ae_form_grid').serialize()
```

i obtain this:

> "id=13&quantita_gen_grid=2&prezzo_gen_grid=120&sconto_gen_grid=&prezzo-15=120&quantita-15=4&sconto-15=&selezionato-16=on&prezzo-16=120&quantita-16=2&sconto-16=&prezzo-14=120&quantita-14=2&sconto-14=&selezionato-17=on&prezzo-17=122&quantita-17=3&sconto-17="

i need to create an object array possibly with this from:

["16":{ prezzo:120,quantita:2,sconto:""},"17":{prezzo:122,quantita:3,sconto:""}]

16 and 17 are from the keys with "selezionato" in the name and prezzo, quantita... are the -16  and -17 ..

i tried with:

```
    $.each(serializedData.split('&'), function (index, elem) {
        var vals = elem.split('=');
        var selected = vals[0].split("-");
        if (selected[0] == "selezionato") {
            sel.push(selected[1])
        }
    })
```

and i have an array of the right key but i can go further.

thanks
F

Comment: Can you please share your form HTML? A better solution than serializing then parsing would be to use JQuery to directly access the desired elements (or even to create the data structure you're looking for)

Comment: it is not easy to copy  html code because it is jinja2 generated. It is a grid of size and color variation and items are similar and different only by a selected checkbox. the problem is tha the form is in a modal so asynchronous and i cant access to the main dom so i need to create this object, store in html5 storage and work whit this data from another windows. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
var input = "id=13&quantita_gen_grid=2&prezzo_gen_grid=120&sconto_gen_grid=&prezzo-15=120&quantita-15=4&sconto-15=&selezionato-16=on&prezzo-16=120&quantita-16=2&sconto-16=&prezzo-14=120&quantita-14=2&sconto-14=&selezionato-17=on&prezzo-17=122&quantita-17=3&sconto-17=";
//["16":{ prezzo:120,quantita:2,sconto:""},"17":{prezzo:122,quantita:3,sconto:""}
var array = input.split('&');
var attributes = ['prezzo', 'quantita', 'sconto'];
var keys = $.map(array, function(value) {
  var string = value.split('=')[0];
  if (string.indexOf(attributes[0]) > -1) return string.split('-')[1];
});
keys = $.unique(keys).sort();
//console.log(JSON.stringify(keys));
var result = []
$.each(keys, function(index, key) {
  var item = {};
  var obj = {};
  $.each(array, function(i, v) {
    var k = v.split('=')[0];
    //console.log("==" + k);
    if (k.indexOf(key) > -1) {
      //console.log("====" + k.split('-')[0]);
      if ($.inArray(k.split('-')[0], attributes) > -1) {
        obj[k.split('-')[0]] = v.split('=')[1];
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
      }
    }

  });
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  item[key] = obj;
  result.push(item);
});
$('span').text(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: if (string.indexOf("selezionato") > -1) return string.split('-')[1];  I changed only this line, i need only selected items. thanks for your answer